# Append text to value-of XLST function

Tags: xslt

How would you append text to `value-of` function. Is it possible? I want to append `-button` after `substring(b:id,1)`:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" value="Check Price">    
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(b:id,1)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>                      
</input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put several value-of and/or `xsl:text` instructions inside an `xsl:attribute`, but simpler would be to use the `concat` function in an attribute value template, which is much less verbose. You only really need `xsl:attribute` when you're creating an attribute with a computed name rather than a fixed one.

```
<input id="{concat(substring(b:id, 1), '-button')}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" value="Check Price"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just:

```
<input id="{b:id,1}-button" ... "/>
```

since anything outside of curly braces is literal text, and  `substring($string, 1)` is the same thing as `$string`.